# Postgres faster order by of calculated field

Tags: postgresql, performance, search

I'm solving the problem of finding similar vectors in the database.

So I have created a function  which calculates the cosine distance (all vectors in database are normalized)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dot_product(IN vector1 float[], IN vector2 float[])
    RETURNS double precision
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT sum(mul) FROM (SELECT v1 * v2 as mul FROM unnest(vector1, vector2) AS t(v1, v2)) as denominator
        );
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cosine_similarity(IN vector1 float[], IN vector2 float[])
    RETURNS double precision
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN (select dot_product(vector1, vector2)  AS similarity_value);
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And I'm searching with this query

```
explain
select *, cosine_similarity(vector, (select vector from image where id = 2852)) as sim
from image
order by sim desc;


Sort  (cost=11091.29..11144.30 rows=21204 width=212)
"  Sort Key: (cosine_similarity((image.vector)::double precision[], ($0)::double precision[])) DESC"
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using image_pkey on image image_1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=18)
          Index Cond: (id = 2852)
  ->  Seq Scan on image  (cost=0.00..7382.26 rows=21204 width=212)
```

although if i don't call order by I get:

```
explain
select *, cosine_similarity(vector, (select vector from image where id = 2852)) as sim
from image;


Seq Scan on image  (cost=8.30..7390.57 rows=21204 width=212)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using image_pkey on image image_1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=18)
          Index Cond: (id = 2852)
```

Therefore, I conclude that my function works fast enough, and 'order by ' is very heavy
Please tell me if anyone has any ideas about this.

**UPDATE**:

I have rewrite my function as @Jeremy and Laurenz Albe advised, but my query still takes a very long time

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cosine_similarity_sql(vector1 float[], vector2 float[]) RETURNS double precision
    AS ' SELECT sum(mul) FROM (SELECT v1 * v2 as mul FROM unnest(vector1, vector2) AS t(v1, v2)) as denominator;'
    LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
PARALLEL SAFE;
```

```
explain analyse
select name, cosine_similarity_sql(vector, (select vector from image where id = 2852)) as sim
from image
order by sim desc;

Sort  (cost=8914.29..8967.30 rows=21204 width=26) (actual time=7692.156..7694.807 rows=20580 loops=1)
"  Sort Key: (cosine_similarity_sql((image.vector)::double precision[], ($0)::double precision[])) DESC"
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2376kB
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using image_pkey on image image_1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = 2852)
  ->  Seq Scan on image  (cost=0.00..7382.26 rows=21204 width=26) (actual time=0.635..7662.591 rows=20580 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.242 ms
Execution Time: 7696.030 ms
```

Comment: It's difficult to conclude much with the analyze, which would actually run the query, but I would try the following: 1) Try writing these as SQL functions instead of plpgsql to see if they can be inlined.  2) Since they don't select from any tables, mark them as immutable and parallel safe. 3) Get rid of the correlated subquery in your query.

Answer (score 1):

The sort is no problem, unless the estimate of 10000 rows is way off.

You will gain most by declaring the functions `IMMUTABLE` like they should be. Moreover, the second function does nothing, get rid of it. Finally, using `LANGUAGE sql` functions may save a little bit, but I don't know if that is measurable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I implement some edits, but I get no positive effect (or very little). Maybe there is someone else to help solve the problem?

Comment: You should add the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` for the query to the question.